# Store Facebook email in parse User table in swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I have the following lines of code. What should I add so that the email also gets stored? **Anything for swift**

```
  @IBAction func fblogin(sender: AnyObject) {
    var permissions = ["public_profile","email"]
    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                var user = PFUser.currentUser()
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
                //let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

            } else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    })
```

Comment: What have you looked at in the APIs and tried?

Comment: https://www.parse.com/questions/how-do-i-fetch-a-facebook-or-twitter-users-email

Comment: Could not find anything for swift. No idea about Objective C

Comment: The logic is the same, class names are generally the same, give it a try

Answer (score 0):

On click of Facebook button this is how it will work considering you have set up parse and facebook.

```
    @IBAction func fblogin(sender: AnyObject) {
    var permissions = ["public_profile","email"]
    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                var user = PFUser.currentUser()
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
                let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

                FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler({connection, result, error in
                    println(result.email);
                    PFUser.currentUser().setObject(result.email as String, forKey: "email")
                    PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackground()


                })
                defaults.setBool(true,forKey:"signedup")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)}

            else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!")
                let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                defaults.setBool(true,forKey:"signedup")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    })





}
```

Comment: Would you mind to add a few words to explain how your code should be used?

Comment: getting error at PFUser.currentUser().setObject(result.email as String, forKey: "email")

Answer (score 0):

in objective c you can solve your problem by this way

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray
                                block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
  if (user) {
    [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
      if (!error) {
        // Store the current user's Facebook ID on the user
        [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[result objectForKey:@"id"]
                                 forKey:@"fbId"];
        [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
      }
    }];
  }
}];
```